# How to underline every line of text, to the end of a block

Tags: css, block, newsletter, underline

So, here's my question, I'm doing a newsletter for a customer, which will look like a postalcard.

I want my layout to look like writing on lines

Can anyone help me achieve what I'm trying to do?
Putting my text in TD tags doesn't work since I don't know the length of each sentences.

Let me know if you need more info!

Thanks :)

Comment: Put in a background image with the lines and adjust your text's line-height to match? You couldn't use regular underlining because that stops when the text does.

Comment: Yeah I thought about background-image but it's for a newsletter and most email client (*outlook*) don't use this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your lines that you need to underline add a style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000"(probably on your containing td)

Comment: This won't work because the lines stop as soon as the text does.

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into this issue where a client "needed" to have a notes section on a print-out with user-entered note text underlined as if on spiral-bound paper. (I've learned to stop asking why.) Why didn't I use a background image? It won't print out, so not an option.

Here's the structure (IDs for clarity):

```
<p id = "p">
    <span id = "span1">
        <span id = "span2">
            sadfa sdfhkas dfjkahsd fhjklasdg f askjldfh jklas djklfh aljks hfjkl hasjdklfg hjlashdjlfgh jlkashdjkl gfhloashdfgh jkladshjkgl haskl dhfiu hajkl fghuasbhfljbahuk bfkljabwehrf bajkls bflaskdjf ljakdfk
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

The following styles are applied:

```
#p {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: justify;
}
#span1 {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#span2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Let's start from the inside here...

`#span2` is given a bottom border in order to create the bulk of the lined-paper look. If we stop here, however, we have a problem: The lines don't extend all the way to the right margin, as has been mentioned previously. This issue we'll get to in a moment.

`#span1`, wrapping #span2, is 50% of the solution to this too-short line problem. I've given it a display property of block, which will allow me to apply a -1px bottom margin, effectively "covering up" the last overhanging line of `#span2` with the bottom edge of #span1. The effect of this isn't worth much until we get to...

`#p` Here the styles we've applied to #span1 pay off. First, we have `text-align: justify` which takes care of most of the bottom-border lines reaching the right margin, save of course for the last line, which now looks really out of place. To take care of this, we apply `border-bottom: 1px solid black` to `#p` which -- because of the -1px bottom margin on our block-styled `#span1` -- overlaps the last, short bottom border and completes the illusion.

Yes, it's sort of kludgy, but when it comes down to the wire and the client's demands can't be adjusted, sometimes a kludge is what you need.

(Note: I wouldn't expect this to work for email formatting... Like I said before, it's something I needed for mimicking that lined-paper look on a printed page.)

Comment: That's thoroughly evil. But it *works*, and I'm using it. Thank-you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I am mistaken, you want something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/eB6tY/

CSS:

```
#postcard .line
{
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="postcard">
    <div class="line">Line 1</div>
    <div class="line">Line 2</div>
    <div class="line">Line 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Im missing the point but could you not do

```
<u> my text here </u>
```

Comment: I think OP wants to simulate the classic lined notepaper you use in school, which means lines even if there's no text to underline.

Comment: I thought that but then the length of sentences wouldnt matter.. so, I thought Id offer it just in case - but as I said, I could be missing the point :)

Answer (score 0):

assuming DIV as your relevant selector

```
div{text-decoration:underline}
```

or inline if you are emailing this...

```
<div style='text-decoration:underline'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a background image with the height of one line of text (plus margin-bottom) and width 1 pixel. The content will be "transparent plus a dot for the place where the line should go"...

Answer (score 0):

This came up in my search so I will post my solution to my problem. I needed to underline an `a` tag that had padding to the end of line that; problem was the underline would start at begining of the element and not the text.

**Problem:**

[image: underline-text-in-a-padded-link-tag-problem.png]

**Solution:**

```
menu .heading a {
    color: #414142 ;
}
.menu .heading a:after {
    /* to get a nice underline that starts at padding-left offset */
    border-bottom: 2px solid #414142;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -0.5em;
}
```

[image: underline-text-in-a-padded-link-tag-solution.png]